# Node Webkit: Using Fullscreen API while beeing in kiosk mode

Tags: fullscreen, node-webkit, kiosk-mode

My node webkit app starts in "kiosk" mode. Now i also want to be able to open an app element (eg a video) in fullscreen mode by using:

`element.webkitRequestFullScreen();`

it obviously doesn't seem to work cause the "kiosk" mode itself seems to be a fullscreen mode.

any ideas?

Comment: if it is cool why don't you leave the kiosk mode for that moment `win.leaveKioskMode();` then `element.webkitRequestFullScreen();`

Comment: when its on kiosk mode it doesn't necessary to be full screen so you can also try `win.leaveFullscreen();` then `element.webkitRequestFullScreen();` and when you are done you could go back to full screen `win.enterFullscreen();` mode.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to make kiosk : true in package.json file like

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "window": {
        "kiosk" : true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you replay, but as i wrote - my app already starts in kiosk mode. thats not the problem. the question was: how to open an element in fullscreen **WHILE** being in kiosk mode?

Comment: @JanViehweger i think this is html page problem and you can just set height, width of element to be maximum hence will take whole screen

Answer (score -1):

This is what i already did. Thought there is an easier way to achive that ;(